# NullPointerException in Adapter using AsyncTask

Tags: java, eclipse, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception, android-arrayadapter

I dont understand why the setAdapter return a nullpointerexception if the array string horariosMontanha is not null.

```
public class LerMontanha extends AsyncTask<String[], Void, String[]> {

    int contador=0;

    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(String[]... urls) {

      String response = null, codigo = null, hora, estado;
      int qt = 0;

      try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
            System.out.println("driver conectado");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://10.0.2.2:3306/savetime", "root", "root");
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select cd_brinquedo from brinquedo where nm_brinquedo = 'montanha russa'");
            if (rs.next()) {
                codigo = rs.getString(1);
            }
            System.out.println("CODIGO= " +codigo );
            ResultSet rs1 = st.executeQuery("select hh_inicio_rodada from rodada where cd_brinquedo = " + codigo);
            while(rs1.next()) {

                hora = rs1.getString(1);
                System.out.println("hora= " + hora);
                Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs2 = stmt.executeQuery("select COUNT(*) from solucaoingressorodada where cd_brinquedo = " + codigo + " and hh_inicio_rodada = '" + hora+ "'");
                if (rs2.next()) {
                    qt = rs2.getInt(1);
                }
                System.out.println("qt= " + qt);
                if (qt<10){
                    estado="Disponível";
                } else {
                    estado ="Fila lotada";
                }
                horariosMontanha[contador] = hora + "         " + estado;
                contador= contador+1;
            }
            rs1.close();
            st.close();
            con.close();

      }
      catch(Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          System.out.println("ERRO: " + e.toString());
      }
    return horariosMontanha;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] horariosMontanha) {
        for (int i = 0; i < contador; i++){
            System.out.println(horariosMontanha[i]);
        }
        if (horariosMontanha != null){
        System.out.println("HORARIOSMONTANHA IS NOT NULL");
        listaMontanha = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstmontanharussa);
        listaMontanha.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, horariosMontanha));
        }
    }
}
```

the logcat shows that horariosMontanha is not null, but set error in ArrayAdpter. What could be my error?

```
06-22 18:10:48.291: I/System.out(996): 12:00:00         Disponível
06-22 18:10:48.291: I/System.out(996): 12:30:00         Disponível
06-22 18:10:48.291: I/System.out(996): HORARIOSMONTANHA IS NOT NULL
06-22 18:10:48.351: D/AndroidRuntime(996): Shutting down VM
06-22 18:10:48.351: W/dalvikvm(996): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
06-22 18:10:48.461: E/AndroidRuntime(996): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-22 18:10:48.461: E/AndroidRuntime(996): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-22 18:10:48.461: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
06-22 18:10:48.461: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
06-22 18:10:48.461: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2255)
06-22 18:10:48.461: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1244)
06-22 18:10:48.461: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1156)
06-22 18:10:48.461: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
06-22 18:10:48.461: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:602)
06-22 18:10:48.461: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:415)
06-22 18:10:48.461: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
06-22 18:10:48.461: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
06-22 18:10:48.461: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
06-22 18:10:48.461: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
06-22 18:10:48.461: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:833)
06-22 18:10:48.461: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
06-22 18:10:48.461: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
06-22 18:10:48.461: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
06-22 18:10:48.461: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
06-22 18:10:48.461: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2148)
06-22 18:10:48.461: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
06-22 18:10:48.461: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1850)
06-22 18:10:48.461: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1102)
06-22 18:10:48.461: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1275)
06-22 18:10:48.461: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
06-22 18:10:48.461: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4214)
06-22 18:10:48.461: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
06-22 18:10:48.461: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
06-22 18:10:48.461: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
06-22 18:10:48.461: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
06-22 18:10:48.461: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
06-22 18:10:48.461: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-22 18:10:48.461: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-22 18:10:48.461: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
06-22 18:10:48.461: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-22 18:10:48.461: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-22 18:10:48.461: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
06-22 18:10:48.461: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-22 18:10:48.461: E/AndroidRuntime(996):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: The stack trace you provided doesn't list any of your packages.  What *specific* line is it throwing the exception?

Comment: the last one : listaMontanha.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, horariosMontanha));

Comment: How do you create **horariosMontanha**? Maybe it has null values after those two printed items.

Comment: i created before the onCreate of MainActivity: String[] horariosMontanha  = new String[30]; and inset the values in the class LerMontanha as show above.